# Method for Focus Change

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a method which initiates on focus change and can be overridden?

My goal is for the program to fetch closest data automatically from database to input fields whenever user changes his focus/presses enter or tab when on corresponding field. I'm still looking for a way to do this when user selects an item by mouse.

I'm aware that this could be implemented on mouse click but I refuse to believe that there is not a general method for focus change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What about something like this:**

```
foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
   ctrl.Enter += new EventHandler(Focus_Changed); // Your method to fire
}
```

Iterate through all controls and add a enter-event. Bind this handler to your method.

**Edit:**
Just in case you are wondering why "Enter" and not "LostFocus" or something like that: From my knowledge not every control got focus-events. As I've seen so far "Enter" is presented for all. Maybe there are exceptions. Should be checked out...

Comment: Thanks. This seems the best answer so far.

Comment: You're welcome. Just take care of the "Enter"-Event. Maybe you have to pick another one (Leave). Cant test it, I'm currently in debugging-mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Control.Enter` event and `Control.Leave` event for that purpose.
See on MSDN [Control.Enter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx) and
[Control.Leave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
textBox1.Enter += textBox1_Enter;
textBox1.Leave += textBox1_Leave;

private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // the control got focus
}

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // the control lost focus
}
```